# how I delete a row in a table in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-dbo

I have a table

```
id h_id t_id
 1   3   1
 2   3   2
 3   3   3
 4   4   2
 5   4   3
```

`id` is the primary key. I have not created a `JTable` for this table. Now I want to delete rows by `h_id`. Are there any method like which I can use without writing a sql DELETE query?

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$row =& $this->getTable('tablename');
$row->delete($pk);
```

Any better solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Are there any mehtod like which I can use without writing a sql delete query?". I think you cannot delete a record or row from a table without using a delete query. Better to go with what you have.

Comment: @vinayjg ok If I create a JTable for this table. can I use $row->delete() method but how to mention the field name? bcoz **h_id** is not primary key and it is not a unique key. If this is not possible I will go for a query. any idea?

Comment: Again it needs a primary key. I had the same problem when I was at my first project. I used the query like delete a record from the table where condition is blah blah and executed it using query() method. It was suggested by my senior. Still I use the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
         $db = & JFactory::getDBO();   
         $query = $db->getQuery(true);
         $query->delete($db->nameQuote('tablename'));             
         $query->where($db->nameQuote('h_id').'='.$db->quote($key));             
         $db->setQuery($query);
         $db->query();
```